# The path of electrons in AC circuit?

Tags: ac, high-voltage, high-current, earth, power-electronics

I have a question regarding the AC circuit shown below. If we ignore the voltage drop caused by the long cable, I think the device will work and the circuit can be considered as a closed circuit.
[image]

Now I am wondering about how the electrons can return back to the source to form a closed path and so a closed circuit!?

As it appears, there are 1000 of Kilometers between GND1 and GND2, or we can say that there is infinite value of ohms (resistance) between the two grounds. So, where is the closed path for the electrons flowing?

Answer (score 4):

While it's common practice on schematics for small (i.e., all in the same place) circuits to show grounds that don't appear to be connected, this is just a convenient way not to clutter up the diagram with all the return paths.

If however you're talking about literally kilometers of physical ground, you'll find that in practice, at least with power delivery, there is always (afaik) a return conductor to ensure a low impedance to complete the circuit. In effect, this return conductor is in parallel with whatever conductance the actual earth connections afford, so some of the current will actually travel through the earth, but mostly it's going to be found in the wire.

RF applications might get away without this return wire, but then RF applications can oft times get away without *either* wire, so I'll leave that aspect for someone else to tackle, should you be interested.

Comment: I don't think that it is just a convenient way in diagram. I work in electrical distribution company and they use it practically without any return conductor.

Comment: @Adban I hope you work in the financial department, because there is ALWAYS a return conductor in power distribution

Comment: @clabacchio i know that there is a neutral for home sockets. Suppose you replace the neutral with a local earth, your device will work, ignore mccb ..etc protection. assume single phase TX.

Comment: @Adban many home sockets have an earth connection, true, but the return path is not that: the power grid is AC, so you are using TWO wires to supply the power, and the return path is always provided through a wire

Comment: @clabacchio the default return path is a neutral wire, the local earth is used for protection. But still if you replace the neutral wire by the local earth (ignore protection equipments) you will end up with a closed circuit. Consider that the end terminal of the neutral at the source is earthed.

Comment: @Adban, Could it be a nearby stepdown transformer is using earth to reference its neutral and it is allowing function?

Comment: @Adban - can you give voltages and currents for examples you're referring to? I'd be rather surprised if they were not high voltage/low current situations.

Comment: @Adban - the other scenario I can think of is three phase Y - if the load is really well balanced, the required neutral would be small. Perhaps 'practically without', as you say; but any neutral current would still largely travel in that wire rather than the ground.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there isn't (assumed that the resistance between the two GNDs is infinite) and there is no closed circuit.

If the potentials are different, there may be an electrostatic discharge when the one with lower absolute potential will try to take charge from the other (giving electrons), but no continuous flow of current will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Earth is actually conductive, even over long distances.  A geologist can probably explain this better than I, but my understanding is that wet soil is chock-full of minerals and various salts.  This makes it conductive.

Rural power delivery is often done with a single live conductor strung on poles, with the return path being two or more long grounds rods driven deep into the soil.  This has lead to some unfortunate problems involving farms with livestock.  I was aware of this when I was a kid many years ago and it is well documented.  Do a Google search for "livestock stray voltage".

Modern power delivery methods now include the return conductor.  That wasn't the case many years ago.

Answer (score -1):

There is a thing called single wire earth return (SWER) common in HVDC systems. You can actually use the earth as a return path , but I still can't make out how the electrons flow. I don't think that there is an actual way for an electron to travel 100km and find its way from one electrode to the other. Research on internet was fruitless..

Comment: There is a difference between electromagnetic waves and charge carriers : electrons, ions... Electrons don't have to travel much. Bogus analogy : The air does not need to move, except minuscule vibrations, to transport a sound.

Comment: Yet there has to be a continous flow of charge, especially in the case of a DC system.

Answer (score -2):

The general mass of earth is zero ohms but it is the connection to earth that adds resistance to the circuit. As pointed out in Australia there is a high voltage network called single wire earth return and it uses a single wire to a transformer and uses the earth to complete the circuit.

Comment: The mass of Earth is about 5.97219 × 10^24 kg ;) SCNR

Comment: How can the mass of the earth be expressed in ohms?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. In earthing systems design we do talk about connecting to "the general mass of the earth", which is done by putting bare conductors in the ground. The old Australian standard used to be that the resistance between your earth conductor and the general mass of earth had to be less than one ohm. (This standard has changed, but it's still a good rule of thumb.) And SWER is definitely a thing.